# How to avoid `nil` error when trying to join strings from different lines

Tags: ruby

I have a file like this:

```
QWWWQV27

ETYUM
2019-01-29 03:20:07  
KJJD_990 

RP04MMB High risk YUZZP 

HHLPPD  
2019-01-23 12:34:13  
CDF55UHM11  

UYRP566_I Low risk ABCX
```

I want to concatenate the date and the next line containing the word `"risk"`, and assign it to a variable.

I have the following code.

```
require 'date'

File.foreach("file.txt",sep="\n") do |line|
    if (DateTime.strptime(line.strip, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') rescue nil)
     date = line.strip  #Here I'm storing the date in variable "date"
     next
    end

    risk = line[/.*risk.*/]
    next unless not (risk.nil?)
    output = date + risk
    p output
end
```

And I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
        from (irb):3333:in `block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):3325:in `foreach'
        from (irb):3325
        from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

When I capture the line that contains `"risk"` and want to concatenate it with the date stored in variable `date`, the content of this variable is `nil`.

I don't know when `date` changes to `nil`. What am I doing wrong? How can I store the date to concatenate it later when the line containing the word `"risk"` appears?

Comment: Is data.nil? a typo? (date.nil?)

Comment: Perhaps remove two negatives: `next if date.nil?` instead of `next unless not (date.nil?)`.

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: Yes, `data.nil?` was a typo, the correct is `risk.nil?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str =<<_
QWWWQV27

ETYUM
2019-01-29 03:20:07  
KJJD_990 

RP04MMB High risk YUZZP 

HHLPPD  
2019-01-23 12:34:13  
CDF55UHM11  

UYRP566_I Low risk ABCX
_

FNAME = 'temp'
File.write(FNAME, str)
  #=> 144
```

```
require 'date'
```

We begin by defining two procs, both of which have one argument, `line`, which will be a line of the file after `line.strip!`.

```
date_r = Proc.new { |line| DateTime.strptime(line,
  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') rescue false }
  #=> #<Proc:0x00005784561a3b28@(irb):567> 
risk_r = Proc.new { |line| line.match? /\brisk\b/i }
  #=> #<Proc:0x00005784561c5610@(irb):569>
```

Next, use [Array#cycle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-cycle) to produce an enumerator `enum`. Each time `p = enum.next` is executed one of the two procs `date_r` and `risk_r` will be assigned to the variable `p`, first `date_r`, then `risk_r`, then `date_r` and so on, forever. Both procs return `true` or `false`.

```
enum = [date_r, risk_r].cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: [#<Proc:0x00005784561a3b28@(irb):567>,
    #<Proc:0x00005784561c5610@(irb):569>]:cycle> 
p = enum.next # initialize p to date_r
  #=> #<Proc:0x00005784561a3b28@(irb):567> 

File.foreach(FNAME).with_object([]) do |line, arr|
  line.strip!
  if p.call(line)
    arr << line
    p = enum.next
  end
end.each_slice(2).map(&:join)
  #=> ["2019-01-29 03:20:07RP04MMB High risk YUZZP",
  #    "2019-01-23 12:34:13UYRP566_I Low risk ABCX"]
```

Note that before `.each_slice(2).map(&:join)` is executed,

```
File.foreach(FNAME).with_object([]) do |line, arr|
  ...
end
  #=> ["2019-01-29 03:20:07", "RP04MMB High risk YUZZP",
  #    "2019-01-23 12:34:13", "UYRP566_I Low risk ABCX"]
```

Comment: Thanks Cary. Your solution it works as usual, but in this case I don't understand many things hehe.    What `Proc.new{...}` is?
, .... How `|line|` in `Proc.new` could be defined before the "other" `line` within `File.foreach` block(is the same variable line)?
, .... What is and how it works the `Enumerator`?
, .... What does `p.call(line)` do?

Comment: `Proc.new` creates a proc which is like a block except it is a Ruby object so it can be passed around. `line` is each proc's argument, which is like a block variable or method argument. Being a variable it could as well be `x`. Each of the two procs `p` are executed by writing `p.call(line)`, where `line` holds the line just read (the value of `line`), after `line.strip!` is executed. `enum.next`, where `enum` is the enumerator,  returns one of the two enumerators, alternating between the two. Clear? (See also my edits to the question.)

Comment: Hi Cary, thanks for your explanation. I understand your code better now. Now, how to do if I want to do a special handling when line matches the date and when line matches the risk? 
for example if element of enumerator is `date_r` then `arr << line` but if element of enumerator is `risk_r` then `arr << line[/(High|Low) risk/]`. This is, apply a regex to `line` to extract the string containing the kind of risk only, and not the other strings before and after "high/low risk".

Comment: Define `rrisk = /\b(?:High|Low) risk\b/` and `prisk = Proc.new { |line| line.match? r }`, and change `arr << line` to `arr << (p==pdate ? line : line[rrisk]` (parentheses needed). `\b` is a *word break*, meaning that `risk\b` ensures the word `"risk"` is not immediately followed by a word character (such as `"y"`) and that `\n(?:High|Low)` ensures that`"H"` or `"L"` is not immediately preceded by a word character. Word characters are upper and lower case letters, digits and the underscore.

Comment: Thanks so much. It seems to work with the additions you suggested.